# Create array with vlookup

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, spreadsheet, gs-vlookup

I want to conditionally grab lines from a database-style spreadsheet in Google Spreadsheets (a list with a name, location, description, price) after checking the value with a vlookup - I've used this a while ago and expected it to `CONTINUE` an array across for the other columns next to the one 'looked up', but it seems my memory fails me here and it just retrieves the 'searched out' value.

```
=vlookup("Yes",'All 2014-15'!A2:G,2)
```

This formula basically finds the first value of the desired rows and should create a 'Selected items from 2014-15' list, but I can't work out how to expand it to produce a list of all the rows I want. Is there a simple way to retrieve this, I've tried playing with `arrayformula` but no success.

I can change the index simply to get the other values across, but if this could be filled out through an array too that would be preferable...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this...

```
=FILTER('All 2014-15'!A2:G,'All 2014-15'!A2:A="Yes")
```

Edit:
As suggested by Immx, added apostrophes to sheet name and the second range changed to A2:G to A2:A assuming the yes/no data is in A column.

Comment: Brillianttt, yeah the sheet name wasn't parsing as it needs apostrophes and then the FILTER function requires a 1-dimensional range (1 x N or N x 1) and if I use the A column it gives me the word Yes a bunch of times - if I change the cell to =FILTER('All 2014-15'!B2:B,'All 2014-15'!A2:A="Yes") it produces the values in B column and I can just copy across for the other columns I want - thanks a lot!